# How to store all user's data separately to smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps, mapping, struct

What is the best way to store users data on smart contract? Suppose we have **n** number of users and we want to store each user's username and his/her other details. For example if i enter my wallet address, to should show only my data. How to achieve this?
Please help thanks :)

I want to achieve this:

```
"address": {
    "data": {},
    "posts": [{
       ...
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, the solution can be this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Users {
    mapping(address => User) _user;

    struct User {
        string _username;
        uint _age;
        // define other information
    }

    function addUser(address _userAddress, string memory _username, uint _age) public {
        _user[_userAddress] = User(_username, _age);
    }

    function getUser(address _address) view public returns(User memory) {
        return _user[_address];
    }
}
```

With the `function addUser()` you'll add the user into a struct.
While when you'll call the `function getUser()`, you can retrieve all of information defined into a struct refers to a specific address.

Comment: so if i switch the wallet address then it show me the other user's data right?

Comment: To view a data from another address, you must call the get User() with the address of the user from which you want to retrieve data

Comment: and can u please suggest me that, i want to add article posting functionality, and it is also user based like if user (A) post article it should saved into his mapping. and i can see the article by iD. How can i achieve it?

Comment: @SyedMuhammedBilal if user posts an article, you can associate the user's wallet address with the article, and save that data in the contract responsible for storing a list of articles.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**

You can archive this via struct mapping.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
contract Test{
        struct user{
          string firstName;
          string lastName;
          uint256 id;   
         }
        mapping(address=>user) public userData;
        function add(address _user,string memory _fname,string memory _lname,uint256 _id) public {
               userData[_user].firstName = _fname;
               userData[_user].lastName = _lname;
               userData[_user].id = _id;
        }
}
```

**Edit 2**

If user not added in user struct and he try to call getUser function it will revert.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
contract Test{
        struct user{
                address _address;
                string firstName;
                string lastName;
                uint256 id;   
         }
        mapping(address=>user) userData;
        function add(address _user,string memory _fname,string memory _lname,uint256 _id) public {
               userData[_user]._address = _user;
               userData[_user].firstName = _fname;
               userData[_user].lastName = _lname;
               userData[_user].id = _id;
        }

        function getUser() public view returns(address){
                require(userData[msg.sender]._address == msg.sender , "You are not allowed.");
                return userData[msg.sender]._address;
        }
}
```

Comment: i also want to add other options like user can also add post. I tried this but the issue i was facing is that on switching different wallets im still able to see first user's data. I want to see only my data if im user is using his wallert

Comment: For this issue you can make userData mapping private and make getfunction for retrive userdata.

Comment: how to add more functionalities like user can also add thier post, i tired it but the issue i was facing is that i cant store it indivisually, means that user (A) post some article on his profile, so user (B) wont able to see it if he is login on the application, how can i do this?

Comment: for this you make separate question this is not part of solidity.